# Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and facing error

> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]' is not a valid selector

when selecting the age from dropdown. The Html code is here

```
<select id="traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]" name="traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]"><option value="0" selected="selected">...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>`
```

i have tried following but same error each time

```
await page.select("#traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]", `${day}`);

await page.evaluate((day) => {
    {

        document.querySelector('#traveller*> option:nth-child(1)').selected = true;
    }
}, day);
```

I guess there is something wrong with the id.

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets, parentheses, and digits all need to be escaped with a backslash so that they don't get treated as special characters.

Since there are *so many* of them in your ID, escaping them all is excessive and would result in a really messy-looking selector, so I recommend using an attribute selector instead:

```
await page.select("[id='traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]']", `${day}`);
```

Comment: I already did it by using above selector. Thanks of your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the brackets properly in your selector. Try this:

```
"#traveller\[36350015\]\[date_of_birth\(3i\)\]"
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I just changed the id provided by you but now new error 
failed to find element matching selector \"#traveller\\[36350015\\]\\[date_of_birth\\(3i\\)\\]\"

Comment: I assumed another formatting here. You must use one backslash to escape the bracktes.

Comment: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#traveller[36350015][date_of_birth(3i)]' is not a valid selector

Comment: Carsten, all the digits need to be escaped too.